# Binning Data in Python versus R?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm trying to rewrite some R code into Python but I'm not getting the same output. I would be grateful if somebody could please point me in the right direction:

R Code:

```
Data_2017_18$ageband3 <- cut(Data_2017_18$age,
                            breaks = c(0, 30, 50, Inf),
                            labels = c(1,2,3))
```

R Output:

```
> freq(as.ordered(Data_2017_18$ageband3))
 as.ordered(Data_2017_18$ageband3) 
       Frequency Percent Cum Percent
1          5123   14.76       14.76
2         11308   32.57       47.33
3         18284   52.67      100.00
 Total     34715  100.00
```

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd

Data_2017_18['ageband3'] = pd.cut(x=NVF_2017_18['age'],
                        bins=[0,30,50,100])
```

Python Output:

```
Data_2017_18.ageband3.value_counts()

 (50, 100]    18175
 (30, 50]     11308
 (0, 30]       5123
 Name: ageband3, dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to match the Python output with the R output, please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output if you increase the `bins` on the python side? You're using `inf` (R) and `100` (python).

Comment: Hi Alex, I've tried that... it's still leaving me short on the 50+ category. Cheers

Comment: Okay, then you should provide an [mcve]. This looks like it's a problem to do with the data you're loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't how the maximum possible value of your data you can use `numpy.inf` or more commonly `np.inf` (if you `import numpy as np`)

Take the following data

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 110, 35000), columns=['age'])

>>>print(df.describe())
                age
count  35000.000000
mean      55.183771
std       31.362987
min        1.000000
25%       28.000000
50%       55.000000
75%       82.000000
max      109.000000
```

Then cut to your desired bins, notice the `np.inf` in the bins list

```
banded = (
    df.groupby( # setup to group original data by the ageband
        pd.cut(df.age, bins=[0, 30, 50, np.inf]) # get the actual binning
        # notice the last bin ends in infinite
    ).size().rename('frequency').to_frame() # count and reshape
)

>>> print(banded.sum())
frequency    35000
```

And if you wish to add those pct/cumpct columns

```
banded['percent'] = banded / banded.sum()
banded['cum_percent'] = banded.percent.cumsum()

>>> print(banded)
              frequency   percent  cum_percent
age
(0.0, 30.0]        9529  0.272257     0.272257
(30.0, 50.0]       6394  0.182686     0.454943
(50.0, inf]       19077  0.545057     1.000000
```

Comment: How would you add labels to that then? i.e. (0.0, 30.0) = "1 to 29"?

Comment: see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas.cut), there is a `labels` parameter that must be array-like and contain `len(bins) - 1` elements

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `value_counts` and pass the `bins`

```
df.age.value_counts(bins=[0, 30, 50, np.inf])
Out[133]: 
(50.0, inf]       19077
(-0.001, 30.0]     9529
(30.0, 50.0]       6394
Name: age, dtype: int64
```